# How does the French T relate to D (from a Chinese perspective)?

Tags: prononciation

1. `t`
   Once I've heard a teacher saying never to pronounce the letter "T" with the sound "T", start with the sound "D" [in English]. So she said we should say [di], but not [ti].
   But when I listen to the books, I've heard the French people start with "T", so I wonder, who is right?
2. `p`
   The same as above. Which sound should I start with? Sound "P" or sound "B"?

Comment: You'd get a more accurate answer by using an example.

Comment: Maybe not an example, but related: why do people write _absorption_ and not _absorbsion_? And why not go the full way to _aptorption_ while we're at it?

Comment: @Gilles, good title edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what I wrote first mabye seems very Chinese English :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But right out of the box, I'd say there is some missing information because T should be pronounced as "Tay", and P as "Pay".

Answer (score 18):

It makes sense from a Chinese teacher. The pinyin *t* is stronger than the French *t*.

But the pinyin *d* is somewhere between the French *t* and French *d*. I often hear the Chinese render the French *t* too softly.

The difference between French *t* and *d* is less in the mouth than in the throat. The *d* sound makes use of the vocal folds, whilst the *t* sound does not.

Neither of them have a strongly aspirated *h* like the pinyin *t* (or even the English *t*, hence the remark from your teacher I guess).

So it's not as simple as making a one-to-one map with Chinese sounds. What you hear as a Chinese native speaker is something between your pinyin *t* and *d* sounds in both cases, and it's hard for you to make the difference. I used to teach Chinese people to make the difference by placing a finger along your throat, and try to pronounce *t* and *d*. When you feel the vocal folds vibrating a lot, that's a French *d*. When you don't, that's a French *t*.

As a side note, it's better to make a strong difference between your *t*'s and *d*'s in French, because the understanding is less easy when *t*'s and *d*'s all sound like *d*'s. :) I'd advise to make the French *t*'s as a gentle and soft pinyin *t* (with lower aspiration than usual), and pronounce French *d*'s like a pinyin *d* while paying attention to make the vocal folds vibrate.

The same distinction applies to the difference between *p* and *b*.

Comment: Yep,when we Chinese read pinyin T, we don't use our vocal folds. Thanks for your answer. Learned a lot from it. Your answer is more deep than what I asked. I just want to know the sound of the french letter, you even answered my next future question---the french t sound and d sound. :-P

Answer (score 5):

To supplement Subtenante's answer, read about [voice onset time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_onset_time).

To summarize: Humans can pronounce a wide spectrum of ([dental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_stop) or [alveolar stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_stop)) consonants, ranging from points with strong voicing (French "di") to points with strong aspiration (English "tea", or perhaps Korean is stronger).  Most languages only contrast 2 points on this spectrum, usually called d and t, but the d and t in one language are different than in another.

Answer (score 2):

"Who is right?"
I would say the French people are right... :-P

Right now, out of the blue, I fail to see examples of pronouncing T as DT or P as B.
In some cases, often when pronouncing foreign words, we can change sounds from what seems to be natural to a French.
I am thinking of "chat" in the sense of chatting, pronounced (and sometime written) tchat, to distinguish from the "cat" sense.
Another example is "Magick", pronounced "madjick".

Comment: "Right now, out of the blue, I fail to see examples of pronouncing T as DT or P as B. " This sentence is very useful. :-D Thanks for your answer.